# Asp.Net Core - Middleware VS. DispatchProxy

Tags: asp.net-core, proxy, aop, middleware, action-filter

I just found the **DispatchProxy** class and wondering if I should wrap my **Repository** and **Service** objects with them (the wrapping is done by factory).

Currently I use **Middleware's** and **ActionFilter's** for logging and authenticating but the proxy seems to be better because with them I should be able to create my code more plattform Independent (they are supported in dot.Net Standard).

Is there a big drawback between Middleware/ActionFilter **vs.** DispatchProxy?

Has anyone experience with the **DispatchProxy** class in professional environments?
Are they much slower because they use delegates?

Thank you for your efforts!

(here an article about the DispatcherProxy: https://dzone.com/articles/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-using-dispatchpro)